# Is there an Angular equivalent to React Fiber?

Tags: angular, reactjs, ngrx, react-fiber

Motivation: I'm working on an app which some parts of it renders **multiple times a second**, and may in some cases perform **heavy rendering**. I would like it to give user action priority over everything else, even in those heavy rendering cases.

I've learn that that react 16 schedule algorithm (also known as React Fiber)

1. **Split** the work handed to the main thread into chunks, preventing overload which can prevent the main thread from rendering UI.
2. Offer a way to give a specific tasks (like user action) **different priority**, so it will be treated before lower-priority tasks.

Is there an **angular mechanism which provide both of these features**?

(I assume that [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx) can provide some advantages, as all actions/events are asynchronous, so the **second feature** is more critical for my case)

Comment: Instead of comparing Angular and React, please specify what is your goal. If it is performance, Angular has many performance utilities (e.g. lazy-loading).

Comment: I'm working on an app which some parts of it renders multiple times a second, and may in some cases perform heavy rendering.
I would like it to give user action priority over everything else, even in those heavy rendering cases.

Comment: Action priority over the rendered parts, or over the whole application ?

Comment: both, but rendering is my main concern.

Comment: What are the rendered parts ? HTML contents, SVGs, 3D ... ?

Comment: It may contain different parts, mostly html-based components / UI libraries components, SVGs and canvas -based components.